# Python - I am trying to run a main logic (game server) loop concurrently with asyncio start_server waiting for TCP traffic

Tags: python, server, python-asyncio

I have a script at the moment which uses `asyncio` to listen on a TCP port for any incoming connections, if a connection is received then it parses the data and sets a class variable to the data received.

This works perfect just to wait for incoming connections - but I cannot figure out how to run a loop concurrent to this waiting for an incoming connection. I am building a server to receive input via TCP, and update things stored within caches in a loop in the main() function.

This is what I have at present:

```
import socket
import binascii
import struct
import asyncio

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 30194
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(incomingData, TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

try:
    loop.run_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Async method to handle incoming connections

async def incomingData(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
    incomingMessage = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print("Received %r from %r" % (incomingMessage, addr))

    # [0] login packet
    if ord(incomingMessage[0]) == 0:
        username = ""
        password = ""
        try:
            usernameLength = ord(incomingMessage[1]) + 2 # plus two for the 2 chars taken up by the hex
            passwordLength = ord(incomingMessage[usernameLength]) + 1 + usernameLength

            for x in range(2,usernameLength):
                username += incomingMessage[x]

            for i in range(usernameLength,passwordLength):
                password += incomingMessage[i]

            loginHandler.username = username
            loginHandler.password = password

    except:
        print("Unexpected error")

writer.write(data)
await writer.drain()
writer.close()
```

However, if I add a loop to encompass `loop.run_forever()` then it only outputs the print line once and never again (I would expect it to print hundreds of  times running in a loop) - for instance:

```
try:
    while True:
        print("debug print?")
        loop.run_forever()
```

Will print only once in execution - how can I have a logic loop running concurrent to the asyncio TCP `start_server` loop?

Comment: the code you provide is work perfectly, it sends data back each time.

Comment: Why would you need a loop around `run_forever`? As the name says, it runs the event loop without exiting, so a loop around it doesn't make sense. Having a loop around calls to `incomingData` won't work when there are multiple `incomingData`s running in parallel (when more than one client connects). If you just want to run some code at the end of `incomingData`, you can just put it there.

Answer (score -2):

You could maybe try multithreading.

So you would create a thread for the two things you are trying to do.

You can look at this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

This is my first answer.

Comment: Thanks for contributing an answer, but this answer unfortunately misses the point of the question. The question is specifically about using the [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) library, and is not resolved by creating a separate thread.